How do I Run a Python script on a virtual server from a local Java project?
I´m trying to run a Python script (main.py) located on a virtual server (IP / Port). I´m running tests at my local machine on Java with Py4j library, which as I´ve found runs on Python 3.11 (my Python version on Virtual Server).
Does anyone have an idea how can i program it. I just need to start the script. It´d be also nice to be able to pass some parameters (but not a requisite). These Parameter are under another script which is called from main.py: Agent(int,bin,bin).
For local dependencies on Java, I use Gradle.
I don´t get why my computer connects to local socket. Response from console:
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53300', transport: 'socket'
Any help would be much apreciated.
Here what I tested so far:
`import py4j.GatewayServer;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

public class PythonScriptRunner
{
  @Test
  public void executePythonScript()
  {
    //IP and POrt of my Virtual Server

    GatewayServer gateway = new GatewayServer("IP", PORT);
    gateway.start();

    //Pfad where the script main.py is located on virtual server
    PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
    interpreter.exec("exec(open('C:\\project\\main.py').read())");

  }
}`


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
